# Gap between electrical connectors

Tags: soldering

Just wondered what the smallest gap between two soldered connections on a electronic item can be. The item is running at 24VDC and the series of 6x is running at 30 amperes.

How much gap can we get away with between the two connectors? The inspection document released has stated that we can multimeter the connectors and as long as they don't touch we are ok, but this seems odd to me.

Comment: at 24 V, electrically if you can see the gap, it's enough. The main problem is keeping a gap, with variations in board etching, and solder bulging over from the pad, a physical problem. Then you'll have rules for minimum spacings set by board manufacturers, or users organisations, and they'll be different depending on the risk of failure.

Comment: I see insulation ("creepage distance") failures semi-often. This is usually due to contamination via solids (dust, metal particles) and liquids (many oils are [hygroscopic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hygroscopic).)  Point is: unless used in a cleanroom environment, plan on contaminants eventually closing that distance.  24V probably would be fine under the solder mask... unless exposed to hydraulic fluid droplets (gets under mask and causes corrosion), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called "minimum electrical clearance" and depends on altitude, coating, etc.  Purely as an example, leads and terminations on bare board from sea level to 3050m at 16-30V require 0.25mm spacing per IPC-2221 (2017).